# CodeIgniter adding session variable to an already defined "named session"

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, session-variables, session-cookies

I already created as session named "verified" as shown below (in my login controller):

```
foreach($result as $row)
{
  $sess_array = array(
       'id' => $row->memberid, //Session field: id.
       'username' => $row->member_userunique //Session field: username.
  );
  // Create a session with a name verified, with the content from the array above.
  $this->session->set_userdata('verified', $sess_array);
}
```

Now, when a user open a page called book (with a controller named book) i want to add one more additional variable called "book_id" to my "verified" session.

This is what i have done

```
function index()
{
   //Add a new varible called book_id
   $this->session->set_userdata('book_id', $titleID);
}
```

When i tried to retrieve the 'book_id' using the following method:

```
    $session_data = $this->session->userdata('verified');
    $article_id = $session_data['book_id'];
    $user_id = $session_data['id'];
```

It only able to retrieve the 'id' however the 'book_id' is not defined. But if do a var_dump() on $this->session->all_userdata() i can see that the 'book_id' session variable has been successfully appended.

After reading the CI documentation about session, i realized that the code above will not work as i have not tell it to which session should i add the variable to.

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: You can retrieve the value of "verified" variable, and add the new "book_id" element to it, and then again store it in the "verified" variable.

Comment: Does this mean i have to re-declare (if i may to say it like this) the $sess_array{} only this time i add a new variable to it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You do as follows in your `index()` method:

```
$session_data = $this->session->userdata('verified');

$session_data['book_id'] = "something";

$this->session->set_userdata("verified", $session_data);
```

This way you retrieve the contents of the variable (i.e. the array that you persisted earlier), you add another key to the array (book_id), and then store it again. Now you will be able to do, as I assume you want to:

```
$sess = $this->session->userdata("verified");
echo $sess['book_id'];
```